# Find a 90% confidence interval for the population variance

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

**The variability in the amount of impurities present in a batch of chemicals used for a particular process depends on the length of time that the process is in operation. The standard deviation for the traditional process is 1.24. A new process has been developed to reduce the variability of impurities. Suppose a random sample of operation times is drawn under the new process. The results are given below:**

**$5.02$, $5.65$, $4.83$, $6.01$, $5.61$, $5.25$, $5.36$, $4.84$, $5.27$, $5.38$, $5.03$, $5.14$, $5.37$, $5.67$, $4.68$, $5.25$**

**(a) Find a 90% confidence interval for the population variance. What assumption do you need to make?**

**(b) Since the purpose of the research is to reduce the variability, the smaller the SD the better. Hence only the upper bound SD is of interest. Find a 90% confidence upper bound for the population standard deviation.**

**(c) Make a statistic inference whether the new process reduces the variability of impurities. Explain.**

*What I have tried so far:*

(a) For the first part, I started by computing the point estimator, where I ended up getting $S = 0.35234$. From there, I used the pivotal quantity $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}$~$\chi^2(n-1)$. In order to computer the confidence interval, I did the following: $$P(\chi_{0.95}^2 \le \frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} \le \chi_{0.05}^2) = P(\frac{1}{\chi_{0.95}^2} \ge \frac{\sigma^2}{(n-1)S^2} \ge \frac{1}{\chi_{0.05}^2}) = P(\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\chi_{0.95}^2} \ge \sigma^2 \ge \frac{(n-1)S^2}{\chi_{0.05}^2}) $$

So the derived confidence interval should come out to be: $(\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\chi_{0.05}^2},\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\chi_{0.95}^2})$ where $n=16$, $S^2 = 0.12414$, $\chi_{0.05}^2 = 24.9958$, and $\chi_{0.95}^2 = 7.2609$. Plugging everything in, I ended up with $(0.074497, 0.25645)$. Here, I believe we have to assume that this is a random sample that follows a normal distribution.

(b) Here I wasn't too sure how to set this up. I thought that if I want the upper limit, I would want to set it up as follows: $$P(\chi_{0.9}^2 \le \frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2})$$ Again, solving this inequality for $\sigma$ (not $\sigma^2$ since we want SD, not variance), I get $$P(\sigma \le \sqrt{\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\chi_{0.9}^2}})$$ Using the same n and $S^2$, and using $\chi_{0.9}^2=8.54675$, I plug everything in to get $P(\sigma \le 0.46677)$

I'm not sure if I did all of these parts right, but any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me you didn't quite finish. I believe you want a 2-sided confidence interval.

If $L$ and $U$ cut 5% from lower and upper tails of $\mathsf{Chisq}(n-1),$ respectively, then from your first displayed equation a 90% CI for $\sigma^2$ is of the form $\left((n-1)S^2/U,\, (n-1)S^2/L\right).$